# Select2: How to select related results

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to see if this is possible with the library Select2. Say I have a list of data as follows:

- Apple
- Basketball
- Banana
- Orange
- Football

Is there a way to show only Apple, Banana, and Orange when I type in "fruit," and show Basketball and Football when I type "Sports." Meaning is there a "related search/tagging" type of functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

The search documentation: https://select2.org/searching

```js
function matchCustom(params, data) {
  const term = $.trim(params.term);

  if (term === "fruit" || term === "sports") {
    if (data.type === term) {
      return data;  
    }
    return null;
  } 

  return data;
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    type: "fruit",
    text: "apple"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "fruit",
    text: "orange"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "sports",
    text: "football"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: "sports",
    text: "basketball"
  }
];

$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({ data, matcher: matchCustom });
});
```

```css
.js-example-basic-single {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
   <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state"></select>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```